# This just bugs me

Tags: for-loop, hashtable, enumeration

Ignore the parameters, just look the end of the for line. Why do I have to write a semicolon before closing my for loop? I get an error if I don't put it there. It's driving me nuts.

```
 for(Enumeration<String> taxes = taxes.keys(); taxes.hasMoreElements();){
                    String aux=impuesto.nextElement()+"<br>";
                    total += aux;
                    taxHeaders += aux;
                }
```

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: -1. Bad title, not constructive, read manual. The ; is the mark after which you can write a statement which will be executed each time, such as i++.

Comment: Generally, compiler errors are there to tell you that you're doing something wrong. Rather than just writing them off as annoying or irksome, you should investigate. Learning the language and its syntax is a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for-loop needs 3 parameters. If you just give 2 parameters with 3rd parameter not being given, compiler expects the loop variant parameter there. Usually -

```
for(iteration variable; condition; increment/decrement )
for(;condition;increment/decrement ){}
for(iteration variable;;increment/decrement) {}
for(;;increment/decrement) {}

...
```

Comment: I thought for loops always needed something concrete as a parameter. Is there a "for each" equivalent to the loop I posted up there?